# Como retirar o nome do projeto na Url do Servlet Java

Tags: java, servlet

tenho uma dúvida e já procurei na internet toda e não encontrei, como diabos eu tiro o nome do projeto da url no java? ex:

```
http://localhost:8084/MeuProjeto/login
```

para

```
http://localhost:8084/login
```

obrigado!

obs: jdk8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, não sei se está usando algum framework como Spring, mas se estiver usando Servlet puro você precisa configurar o arquivo web.xml do projeto:

Algo assim:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pacote.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    // Classe servlet que responde por essa URL
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name> 
    // URL que deseja mapear
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Para criar o arquivo no NetBeans:**
1. No menu superior clicar em Arquivo, escolher Novo Arquivo.
2. Na tela que abrir, selecionar categoria Web, então selecionar Standard Deployment Descriptor.
3. Clicar em Próximo.
4. Clicar em Finalizar. O arquivo web.xml será criado no diretório web/WEB-INF/.

Comment: Boa noite amigo, e sim, estou usando servlet puro. Só tem um porém, quando eu criei o projeto não selecionei para gerar o web.xml, e sou bem leigo em java, ainda há como gerar ele ou preciso copiar de algum lugar?

Comment: Everton Neri, Considerando que esteja usando a IDE Eclipse: Clique com o botão direito no projeto -> Java EE Tools -> Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub. Então, será gerado: /[NOME_PROJETO]/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: @pss1suporte na verdade estou usando o NetBeans, e justamente pra ele eu não encontrei a solução

Comment: @Everton Neri Inclui na resposta acima como encontrar essa configuração dentro do Netbeans. Abraço.